# Dynamical creation of Spring Data Repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way of Autowiring Spring Data `JpaRepositories` without declaring repository interfaces for each entity Bean?

Like:

```
@Autowired
JpaRepository<Person, Integer> repository;
```

Instead of:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
}

@Autowired
JpaRepository<Person, Integer> repository;
```

Comment: You probably could pack them in one configuration definition, but then you could not be able to do much

Answer (score 1):

So I found out there is a workaround using `SimpleJpaRepository`:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;


JpaRepository<Person, Integer> repository = new SimpleJpaRepository<>(Person.class, entityManager);
```

It's a little hacky (and not autowireable) but it works.

Comment: To have then autowirable you could define those in configuration

Comment: @Sarief may you give an example?

Comment: give me 10 hours, I'm busy atm)

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid not.

The interface that you create and mark as a `@Repository` is used to create a proxy that implements any of the additional functionality that you add to said interface.

In the case that you've highlighted above, where you are not adding any additional functionality I can see why such an approach would be appealing, however I think it's an edge case and I doubt it would be worth Spring's time in treating it as a special case.

You can implement a generic repository yourself for this case, if you think it's worth it, however I think having the Repository interfaces is useful and make the code more readable.

Comment: Well in the case of 5000 isomorphic entities sharing an `Integer` primary key @StuPointerException EDIT: But they are created by spring at runtime, so there has to be the functionality.

Comment: Not concrete class but proxy. At startup. How could system know how much beans you need?